# Linear Combination of Parallel Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I know this is a simple question but I'm getting a bit confused about it.

So let's say we have three vectors, A, B, and C. A and B are parallel each other but C isn't parallel to either one. I know in that case then C is not a linear combination of A and B.

But if A and B are parallel and C is only parallel to A, would we still have an infinite amount of solutions?

Comment: Being parallel is generally considered a transitive property, i.e. if A is parallel to B and B is parallel to C then A is parallel to C, so what you're asking for can't happen.

Comment: Oh okay thank you! I just had one more question, would being parallel mean that there is an infinite amount of solutions to that linear combination? or would that not be possible because parallel lines can never intersect @ConMan

Comment: If the vectors are parallel, then they are scalar multiples of each other, i.e. A = kB for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ (assuming they're all non-zero).  So yes, you'll have an infinite number of solutions because you then have $C = aA + bB = akB + bB = (ak + b)B$ which for any value of $b$ you can find a value of $a$ to make it work.